# codingBat xyzMiddle fails in other tests

Tags: java, string

This is my task:
Given a string, does "xyz" appear in the middle of the string? To define middle, we'll say that the number of chars to the left and right of the "xyz" must differ by at most one.

The problem description and the failures in `others` use case can be seen by using the code below [here](http://codingbat.com/prob/p159772)

xyzMiddle("AAxyzBB") → true

xyzMiddle("AxyzBB") → true

xyzMiddle("AxyzBBB") → false

My solution is below. Since I can't see what 'other tests' are, please help me spot the problem. My method is to check if 'y' appears in the middle for odd or even a String.

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
  if (str.indexOf("xyz") < 0) return false;
  int l = str.length();
  int m = l / 2;
  if (l % 2 != 0) {
   if (str.charAt(m) != 'y') return false;
  }
  else {
   if (str.charAt(m) != 'y' && str.charAt(m - 1) != 'y') return false;
  }
  return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that you are simply `returning false in case the string in question has` **odd** `length`

Which is actually not true, `the pass use-cases` for this task can be mathematically divided like below:

> 1)With `xyz` present in the middle and there is a string of length `x + 1` and `x` to either the left or right of it.

taking length of string `xyz` as 3 the total length comes out to be:

`(x) + 3 + (x + 1)` = `2x + 4`   --->**Always even**
 so in the case above we just check is `xyz` is in the middle or not and return accordingly which is already handled in your code.

> 2) With `xyz` present in the middle and there are strings of length `x`  to the left or right of it.

Again taking length of string `xyz` as 3 the total length comes out to be:

`(x) + 3 + (x)` = `2x + 3`   --->**Always odd**

Hence as per your solution to return `true` in this case(last line of code) you need to filter out the cases when `length is odd` but `xyz` is not in the middle as below:

```
if (!(str.substring((m - 1), m + 2).equals("xyz"))) 
   return false;
```

With this included your solutions looks like as below:

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
  if (str.indexOf("xyz") < 0) return false;
  int l = str.length();
  int m = l / 2;
  if (l % 2 != 0) {
   if (!(str.substring((m - 1), m + 2).equals("xyz"))) 
   return false;
  }
  else {
   if (str.charAt(m) != 'y' && str.charAt(m - 1) != 'y') return false;
  }
  return true; 
}
```

Now it passes all the tests on codingBat.

Comment: Got it! Input like "xyzyabc" could give wrong result in my code. Thanks.

Comment: I believe it's AAxyzBB or AxyzA which could as explained in my answer as these are odd length strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str.length() <3) return false;

   int ind = str.indexOf("xyz", str.length()/2 - 3) ;
   String first = str.substring(0, ind);
   String second = str.substring(ind+3);

  return (first.length() == second.length() || first.length() +1 == second.length() || first.length() == second.length() + 1);
```